# Continuous model of geographic direction (e.g. as ML predictor)

Tags: geography, 360-degrees

Imagine the geographical direction from N, over NNE, NE, E ,... and so on. They are also represented from 0 to 360 degrees.

So far so easy.

Now I want to use the arc degree as a predictor in a machine learning model.

The problem is the break between 360 and 1 degrees, which is physically similar, but not numeric.

Ideas how to avoid this break?

Comment: Don't you get the direction inputs as numeric angle values in the first place? In other words, do you get *only* discrete compass points as direction input?

Comment: Hi Mustafa, I do have the data in degrees (0-360)

Comment: So why does 360 degrees raise an issue? If you are getting values >= 360 then did you try using the modulus operator? For instance `360 % 360` gives 0 or `361 % 360` gives 1 degree.